# custom print commands in gnome

Tags: printing, scripts

I work in a situation where printing requires a script that I have written.
I'm wondering how to add a command (in this case, my script) as a printer in gnome so that it appears in applications like evince.

My goal is to be able to print from evince through the script that I wrote.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try adding it as a custom print option? If you go to System Settings/ Printing/ *right-click your default printer*  Properties/ Job Options there is an option to manually add something there:

[image: Printer options]

Can you test and see if your script (or a pointer to it) can be entered here?

Comment: thanks for the answer.  the printer does not visible on the network.  what the script does is ssh the file to a remote server and then evoke the lpr command there.  i would like to be able to create a printer in the printing dialogue that is not visible on the network.

Comment: @krumpelstiltskin sorry, no clue how to do that. Don't worry about the Tumbleweed badge, either. I've got one too.

Answer (score 0):

Few options my side:

- Share that printer into network through CUPS/IPP
- If it has an internal port but for some reasons don't want to open it to network. You may use an SSH Tunnel. Then install it directly as IPP printer for 2nd PC
- Print in a file, save into a specific folder, then your script handle it from there using `rsync`(`ssh`), `cron`,...